# Oracle SQL: trying to create tables with certain constraints but not able to add record. where is it going wrong?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, create-table

These are the tables i am trying to create. i am not able to find the mistake here at all.

```
CREATE TABLE Pharmaceutical (
PharName     VARCHAR(30),
PharTelephone    VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY (PharName)
);

CREATE TABLE Doctor (
DID     VARCHAR2(20),
DName       VARCHAR2(50),
Specialty   VARCHAR2(70),
YearOfExp   NUMBER,
PRIMARY KEY (DID)
);

CREATE TABLE Patient (
PID     VARCHAR2(20),
PName       VARCHAR2(50),
PDOB        DATE,
PAddress    VARCHAR2(70),
PPostalCode VARCHAR2(12),
FamilyDoctor    VARCHAR2(20),
PRIMARY KEY (PID),
FOREIGN KEY (FamilyDoctor) REFERENCES Doctor(DID)
);

CREATE TABLE Drug (
PharName    VARCHAR2(30),
Tradename   VARCHAR2(30),
Formula     VARCHAR2(70),
PRIMARY KEY (PharName, Tradename),
FOREIGN KEY (PharName) REFERENCES Pharmaceutical(PharName)
);

CREATE TABLE Prescription (
DID     VARCHAR2(20),
PID     VARCHAR2(20),
PharName    VARCHAR2(30),
Tradename   VARCHAR2(30),
PrescriptionDT  DATE,
Quantity    NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT checkQuantity CHECK (Quantity>0 AND Quantity<31),

PRIMARY KEY (DID, PID, PharName, Tradename, PrescriptionDT),
FOREIGN KEY (DID) REFERENCES Doctor(DID),
FOREIGN KEY (PID) REFERENCES Patient(PID),
FOREIGN KEY (PharName, Tradename) REFERENCES Drug(PharName, Tradename),
);
```

i also use drop.sql, to drop the tables:

```
DROP TABLE Pharmaceutical PURGE;
DROP TABLE Doctor PURGE;
DROP TABLE Patient PURGE;
DROP TABLE Drug PURGE;
DROP TABLE Prescription PURGE;
```

thank you!

P.S. --> removed the 'add' from the add contraint part. this is the error i get:

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "PRIMARY KEY ..." - rest of line ignored.
getting this error for the last table's primary key and all of it's foreign keys, so assumed that the problem is with the contraint but i may be wrong.

Comment: @NewbeeDev - your statement is completely incorrect. You can only have one primary key, but the primary key can consist of multiple fields. Thanks.

Comment: if you are using oracle then you have to write 'CONSTRAINT' before PRIMARY KEY and/or FOREIGN KEY too

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of table `Prescription`, the last line before the ending `);` reads

```
FOREIGN KEY (PharName, Tradename) REFERENCES Drug(PharName, Tradename),
```

Get rid of the trailing comma.

Best of luck.